# Enviar un TAB a DGV desde un objeto aparte

Tags: c#

espero que este bien.

Les explico que necesito: tengo un DGV de facturas al cual mando un dato dependiendo de la unidad de medida que tenga el articulo. EJ: **ARTICULO_1** se vende por **UNIDAD**, entonces tiene **X** precio. La cosa es que cuando paso el Articulo al DGV de factura llamo los precios desde la BD y tengo el problema de que, a pesar de que se agregan los artículos al DGV de factura, los precios solo van a la 1ra casilla.
Si pudiera subir un video se los mostraría, pero aquí esta el diseño del formulario y los códigos para que puedan entender de lo que les hablo:

[image: Diseño del formulario]

```
string buscar = "Select Cant_P, Precio, impuesto from DetArticulos, items where codigo = codigoart and CodigoArt = '" + dgvArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells["Item"].Value.ToString() + "'";
string srch = "select Tipo, Precio from DetArticulos where CodigoArt = '" + dgvArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells["Item"].Value.ToString() + "' and Cant_P = (Select min(Cant_P) from DetArticulos)";

dgvFactura.Rows.Add(dgvArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells["Item"].Value.ToString(), dgvArticulos.CurrentRow.Cells["Detalle"].Value.ToString());
dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Unidad"].Value = funcion.Llenartxt(srch, "Tipo");
dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Cantidad"].Value = 1;
dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Precio"].Value = funcion.Llenartxt(srch, "Precio");

dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Precio"].Value = funcion.Llenartxt(buscar, "Precio");
dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["UxCant"].Value = funcion.Llenartxt(buscar, "Cant_P");
dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["TaxFac"].Value = funcion.Llenartxt(buscar, "impuesto");
dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["UxP"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Cantidad"].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["UxCant"].Value);
```

**dgvFactura** es el DGV grande

**dgvArticulo** es el pequeño, donde se encuentran los artículos.

lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que al agregar los artículos en el dgvFactura, salte al siguiente que se agregue para luego agregar los precios elegidos (esta ultima parte ya la tengo controlada, lo que me falta es el salto de linea)